# What is the benefit of using CLI in Salesforce DX?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, continuous-integration

I am wondering why we are using CLI in Salesforce DX over GUI. What are the real benefits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Automation. Using the CLI means that you can set up entire processes, such as CI/CD (Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery). For example, you can make a script to create a new scratch org, load all the metadata to that scratch org, and upload new records to use as development data, etc, all in a single step.

Advanced Use Cases. The GUI doesn't present all possible functions and all possible optional parameters. Using the CLI allows you to access all of the features of DX.

Developer Friendly. Some developers prefer using the keyboard instead of the mouse as much as possible. It is often easier to remember which command to type than to have to remember which area of the screen you need to click on to the get the correct function you're looking for.

---

A GUI has, for the majority of computing history, been nothing more than a series of menus that eventually call the CLI it covers. Sometimes the GUI does a good job of presenting every single option, but *most* of the time, it usually covers only the "basic" or most commonly used features. To get the best use out of most CLI tools, you need to use the CLI directly.